# FB FQL query comment does not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I use `Facebook PHP SDK`  and  I have **FQL** query:

```sql
SELECT fromid,
       text,
       id, time,
       username,
       xid,
       object_id
FROM   comment
WHERE  time > $from
       AND time < $to
       AND xid IN (
               SELECT xid
               FROM   comments_info
               WHERE  app_id = $appid
                      AND updated_time > $from
                      AND updated_time < $to)
ORDER BY time desc
```

It worked some time ago. Query returns null now.

I tried query

```sql
SELECT count
FROM   comments_info
WHERE  app_id = $appid
```

And script return

```sql
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 2: Service temporarily unavailable thrown in...
```

Comment: Facebook might be down...?

Comment: At least a few days? I do not believe it...but everything is possible...

Comment: since July 10, 2013 they are completely dropping support for the 'xid'...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know it's old but I ran into the same situation fetching albums by aid... The problem was that some of the the albums didn't exist anymore.